# Limit Facebook Share dialog Size

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog

How can I limit the Facebook share dialog size.

I'm using the Javascript SDK, this is my test code.

Test site is [here](http://www.fuckm.tv/test.html). CLick the 'contact' button to envoke the dialog. The popup resizes to use a very large image size. This is the image specified in the OG:Image tags, but I'd prefer the dialog box to use a small image, and be a set dimension.

Any ideas?

```
        FB.ui(
         {
           method: 'feed',
           name: $(document).find("title").text(),
           link: location.href
         },
         function(response) {
           if (response && response.post_id) {
             alert('Post was published.');
           } else {
             alert('Post was not published.');
           }
         }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually pass an image to the dialog by adding `picture` to the FB.ui function, so it doesn't use the image specified in the OG tags. You can then set the URL to the smaller image you want to use.

Example:

```
FB.ui( {
        method: 'feed',
        name: $(document).find("title").text(),
        link: location.href,
        picture: '{url_to_picture}'
     }, function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
            alert('Post was not published.');
        }
     }
);
```